# SSRS Multiple Dates returned from Dataset, want to display 1 date per column

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I apologize if this is a stupid question..as I am new to SSRS. I have a dataset that returns about 15 dates e.g

01/01/2013

01/05/2013

01/20/2013

01/25/2013

..etc

and I want to put each one of those dates in a new column next to itself like the following:

Day1          Day2              Day3       Day 5

01/01/2013 01/05/2013 01/20/2013 01/25/2013

any idea on how to do so? I would really appreciate the help

Comment: That is one stupid question!  Okay, I'm joking.  But you really shouldn't start out a question that way.  You can do it with a Matrix (see @mmarie's answer) or pivot in SQL.  Whichever you are more comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

Build a table/matrix and create a column group that contains your date field. It will expand the dates out horizontally when it renders. Here is a [link](http://popbi.wordpress.com/2012/03/02/ssrs-how-to-add-a-column-group-to-an-existing-table/) that contains instructions to add a column group to an existing table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed number of dates (15 in your case) then you can  use pivot in SQL and let your dataset return dates in horizontal format (i.e 1 row with 15 columns) otherwise you can use column grouping to achieve this.

Thanks,
Neeraj